# Make Sinatra Helpers available only in some routes (modular application)

Tags: sinatra, helper, modular

I have two different versions of an application that use slightly different versions of some methods.

```
module Sinatra
  class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
    helpers Sinatra::Version1
    helpers Sinatra::Version2
  end
end

module Sinatra
  module Version1
    def say_hello
      puts "Hello from Version1"
    end
  end
  helpers Version1
end

module Sinatra
  module Version2
    def say_hello
      puts "Hello from Version2"
    end
  end
  helpers Version2
end
```

I realize that helpers specified this way are "top level" and are made available to all routes.

I would like to have the different versions of the methods available to different routes. Is there some way to accomplish this within a modular application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you split your application into two different modular classes which "include" the helpers as necessary. For instance:

```
# config.ru

require './app.rb'

map('/one') do
  run MyApp1
end

map('/two') do
  run MyApp2
end


# app.rb
# helper modules same as you've mentioned above.

class MyApp1 < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::Version1

  get '/' do
    say_hello
  end
end

class MyApp2 < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::Version2

  get '/' do
    say_hello
  end
end
```

Whether this is the best way to go about is something I still need to ponder.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.